problem to align matrix system
I would like to align the system of equations as follows.

unfortunately what I get is not aligned

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\nonumber
D_{t_{0}} & = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
D\\ 
\tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
\forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus {t_{0}} \\
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& = \left\{\begin{matrix} \\
\tau(t_{i}) - \tau(t_{j}) \leq b_{i,j} \\ 
\tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
\forall t_{i}, t_{j} \in T_{e}(m) \cup \left \{t_{*} \right \} \mid  t_{i} \neq t_{j}\\ 
\forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus \left \{ t_{0} \right \}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{split}
\end{align}


You don't want matrix that centers the columns, but aligned.
And you don't want align with \nonumber, but just equation*.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
D_{t_{0}} & = 
\left\{\begin{aligned}
  & D \\
  & \tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
  & \forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus \{ t_{0} \} \\
\end{aligned}\right.
\\
& =
\left\{\begin{aligned}
& \tau(t_{i}) - \tau(t_{j}) \leq b_{i,j} \\ 
& \tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
& \forall t_{i}, t_{j} \in T_{e}(m) \cup \{t_{*} \} \mid  t_{i} \neq t_{j}\\ 
& \forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus \{ t_{0} \}
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


I fixed \{t_0\} instead of {t_0} and removed useless \left and \right declarations.
EDIT
In response to comments, here's a version that doesn't add unwanted space at the right.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{system}{}{%
  \left\{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{}}
}{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
D_{t_{0}} & = 
\begin{system}
  D \\
  \tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
  \forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus \{ t_{0} \}
\end{system}
\\
& =
\begin{system}
  \tau(t_{i}) - \tau(t_{j}) \leq b_{i,j} \\ 
  \tau(t_{0}) - \tau(t_{h}) \leq 0\\ 
  \forall t_{i}, t_{j} \in T_{e}(m) \cup \{t_{*} \} \mid  t_{i} \neq t_{j}\\ 
  \forall t_{h} \in T_{e}(m) \setminus \{ t_{0} \}
\end{system}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Why even use aligned here? Isn't this the same as the cases env if one removes the & (less typing)

@daleif No: cases would add unwanted space at the right.

With the code given in your answer I see no difference between using cases (without the &'s) and aligned.

@daleif OK, I shoul've used alignedat or an array.
